# Issues with checking if a number goes into another in Python

Tags: python, arrays, algebra

I am currently trying to create a computer program which can factor trinomials. For part of my algorithm, I need to check if the smallest coefficient goes into the larger ones. Currently, I have been storing the coefficients in an array (sorted in ascending order). To check if the numbers go into one another, I use this code:

```
if (array[1] % array[0]) and (array[2] % array[0]) == 0:
    print "YAY"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

But, when I tried to enter the values 3, 6, and 9 into my array, the program responded with `FAIL`. Why is this?

Comment: Why was this downvoted? Because of the possibility of homework?

Comment: upvoted - for narrowing right down to the code that is failing. Much nicer than having to trawl through the whole program

Comment: @TankorSmash IDK - also, this was not homework - I have always wondered about how to apply the algebra that we learn in school to python programming.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to change,

```
if (array[1] % array[0]) and (array[2] % array[0]) == 0:
```

to this,

```
if (array[1] % array[0]) == 0 and (array[2] % array[0]) == 0:
```

No language I know of allows the type of comparison you are trying to write. Another way to express it, which may be more inline with the logic of it, would be:

```
if array[1] % array[0] == array[2] % array[0] == 0:
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem here is with the logic in the if condition. As it is, it is testing:

```
1. if (array[1] % array[0]) ) is TRUE
2. if (array[2] & array[0]) == 0
```

change this to:

```
if (array[1] % array[0]) == 0 and (array[2] % array[0]) == 0:
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
if (array[1] % array[0] == 0) and (array[2] % array[0] == 0):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditional has two components, but you only compare the second one.  Try this:

```
if (array[1] % array[0]) == 0 and (array[2] % array[0]) == 0:
    print "YAY"
else:
    print "FAIL"
```

Your issue is that `(array[1] % array[0])` is tested alone - if the remainder is zero, like in your example, it evaluates to false (0 is false, <> 0 is true).